# Re read message which not receive acknowledgement after a certain time?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I want to make a Kafka listener such that if after a certain time if acknowledgment not receive than Kafka consume that message automatically. Which configuration i should use ?

Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: Guess you need to be a bit more specific. What acknowledgment do you mean?

Comment: In kafka if you consume a message than kafka consumer send a message to kafka queue that it read message you can delete it